# Do not allow to enter special characters without digits

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm using JavaScript regex to replace digits with (",",".") to format currency. But there is problem on validating this strings. It allows me to enter this special characters (",",".") without digits like this "...,...".
Here is my regex :

```
currency.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
```

Can anyone have idea about how to validate for this to not allow user can enter "," and "." without digits?
Thanks

Comment: post some ex for valid and invalid matches.

Comment: for example : valid string "10,000.00-1,000" and invalid string "...---..."

Comment: The simplest is `if (!str.match(/\d/)) {alert('Invalid input');}` - which requires at least one digit.  Of course that does not mean the string is a valid number, but it does preclude the input you have proposed.

Comment: How could i check validation for this string "00.00" or "0.0" or "0000.00", or "00-00" or "00.0-0.00"?

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```
 var patt = /^\d{1,},\d{3,}\.?\d{0,}$/;
```

example :

```html
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
         <script>
             var patt = /^\d{1,},\d{3,}\.?\d{0,}$/;
             var str = "1,000";
             if(patt.test(str))
                 alert("Valid");
             else
                 alert("Invalid");
             
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, How could i check validation for this string "00.00" or "0.0" or "0000.00", or "00-00" or "00.0-0.00"?